# gpgkeys: key C927EBE00F1B0520 not found on keyserver

Tags: command-line, update-manager, gnupg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I fix the GPG error “NO_PUBKEY”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

I am using 10.04 LTS - Lucid Lynx.

I shutdown the computer while a software update was running. Then after I restarted my computer and while the update manager was running, I got this error:

> Could not download all repository indexes
>
> The repository may no longer be available or could not be contacted because of network
> problems. If available an older version of the failed index will be
> used. Otherwise the repository will be ignored. Check your network
> connection and ensure the repository address in the preferences is
> correct.
>
> ```
> GPG error: http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com ./
> Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
> NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
> Failed to fetch  http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/**DISTRIBUTION**/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz
> 404  Not Found
> ```

I went through the answers to [How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

and I tried this

```
$ sudo launchpad-getkeys 
Please wait... launchpad-getkeys is running an update so it can detect the missing GPG keys
Trying to import all the missing keys
gpg: requesting key 0F1B0520 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key C927EBE00F1B0520 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
launchpad-getkeys has finished importing all missing GPG keys. 
Try running sudo apt-get update - you shouldn't see any key 
errors anymore
```

But when I run `sudo apt-get update` again, it again shows that the key was not found on the keyserver. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors in your question, one of them producing the GPG error.

```
 GPG error: http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com ./
 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
 NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
```

This GPG error is not related to Launchpad and as a result the keys cannot be retrieved with `launchpad-getkeys`. Following the instructions on http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/linux/readme, you have to add the key with:

```
wget -q -O - http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -
```

Be aware that external repositories may be unsafe, only add repositories and keys that you really trust.

```
Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu/dists/\*\*DISTRIBUTION\*\*/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz 404 Not Found
```

You've made a mistake in following instructions. Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `**DISTRIBUTION**` with your actual distribution in lowercase (e.g. `oneiric`). Here's a command to do this automatically:

```
sudo sed -i /etc/apt/sources.list "s/\*\*DISTRIBUTION\*\*/$(lsb_release -sc)/"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `sources.list` file replace `**DISTRIBUTION**` with the actual name of the distribution (in this case `lucid`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo aptitude update
```

The more elaborated & updated code for Ubuntu without aptitude is:

```
sudo -i  
apt-get clean  
cd /var/lib/apt  
mv lists lists.old  
mkdir -p lists/partial  
apt-get clean  
apt-get update
```

The solution works for the heroku toolbelt GPG key error

Source: [How do I fix the GPG error no pubkey](http://fortunatofusca.wordpress.com/linux/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no_pubkey/)

Comment: It shows following output,  Fetched 13.4MB in 4min 26s (50.3kB/s) 
Reading package lists... Done 
W: GPG error: http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu/ ./ Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/toolbelt.herokuapp.com_ubuntu_._Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/ubuntu/ ./ Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/toolbelt.herokuapp.com_ubuntu_._Packages)

Current status: 28973 new [+28962].

Comment: Try to do 
`curl http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/apt/release.key | apt-key add -`
`apt-get update`

Comment: I got the following output when the command run      `% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
102  1737  102  1737    0     0    353      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--   476
gpg: no writable keyring found: eof
gpg: error reading `-': general error
gpg: import from `-' failed: general error`

Comment: Try to do it manually, download `http://toolbelt.herokuapp.com/apt/release.key` file, go where you download the file, for example, `cd /home/user/downloads/` and then `apt-key add release.key` and finally `apt-get update`.