# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY

Tags: 14.04, apt, updates, gnupg

When I look for my error key number `0429ACCAF7AA50B3`, it is not in the database, thus I cannot receive or generate anything even none of this did not work:

- http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.cz/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html#comment-form

Please, do you know what to do next? Thank you!

This is what it shows:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0429ACCAF7AA50B3
[sudo] password for jiri: 
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.ag55619bV6 --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nilarimogard-webupd8.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team-y-ppa-manager.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0429ACCAF7AA50B3
gpg: requesting key F7AA50B3 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key 0429ACCAF7AA50B3 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Comment: You have to contact the maintainer of the repository you are using. What repository are you using ?

Comment: @EliahKagan - I am not sure if this is a duplicate as the key is missing either from the repository or the key server or both

Comment: @bodhi.zazen You're right, [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) probably doesn't answer this. (I've retracted my close vote.) [This other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68645/gpgkeys-key-c927ebe00f1b0520-not-found-on-keyserver) might help, but I'm not sure.